# What are the Enlightenment (e17) shortcut keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys

In particular, I'd like to launch programs from the keyboard. I expected the windows key (Super) to launch the launcher ("Run Everything")

The launcher built into e17 looks really nice, so you can launch things by typing, but I don't know the keyboard shortcut to open it.

Is there a list of hotkeys for elementary e17 window manager?

I did `sudo apt-get install e17` and logged into it.

Comment: did you try Alt+Esc ?

Answer (score 0):

go to:

```
Menu
Settings Panel
Key Bindings
Add
```

then press the desired Key and associated command.

hope is that you want?